# Pop-Under : only one time per session and Onload

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm searching on google but i can't find a good solution. I'm searching a pop under script which open a new url window but only once time per seesion. i found a lot of script but the open a new window just for the onclick ...

```html
<script>



function jsPopunder(sUrl, sConfig) {

    sConfig = (sConfig || {});

    var sName   = (sConfig.name   || Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1));
    var sWidth  = (sConfig.width  || window.innerWidth);
    var sHeight = (sConfig.height || window.innerHeight);

    var sPosX = (typeof(sConfig.left)!= 'undefined') ? sConfig.left.toString() : window.screenX;
    var sPosY = (typeof(sConfig.top) != 'undefined') ? sConfig.top.toString()  : window.screenY;

    /* capping */
    var sWait = (sConfig.wait || 3600); sWait = (sWait*1000);
    var sCap  = (sConfig.cap  || 2);

    /* cookie stuff */
    var popsToday = 0;
    var cookie = (sConfig.cookie || '__.popunder');

    var browser = function() {
        var n = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        var b = {
            webkit: /webkit/.test(n),
            mozilla: (/mozilla/.test(n)) && (!/(compatible|webkit)/.test(n)),
            chrome: /chrome/.test(n),
            msie: (/msie/.test(n)) && (!/opera/.test(n)),
            firefox: /firefox/.test(n),
            safari: (/safari/.test(n) && !(/chrome/.test(n))),
            opera: /opera/.test(n)
        };
        b.version = (b.safari) ? (n.match(/.+(?:ri)[\/: ]([\d.]+)/) || [])[1] : (n.match(/.+(?:ox|me|ra|ie)[\/: ]([\d.]+)/) || [])[1];
        return b;
    }();


    function isCapped() {
        try {
            popsToday = Math.floor(document.cookie.split(cookie+'Cap=')[1].split(';')[0]);
        } catch(err){}
        return (sCap<=popsToday || document.cookie.indexOf(cookie+'=') !== -1);
    }


    function openIt(sUrl, sName, sOptions) {
        if (isCapped()) return;

        var _parent = (top != self && typeof(top.document.location.toString())==='string') ? top : self;
        var popunder = _parent.window.open(sUrl, sName, sOptions);

        if (popunder) {
            popunder.blur();

            setTimeout(function() {
                document.onclick = function() { return; };
                document.onmousedown = function() { return; };
            }, 1000);

            var now = new Date();
            document.cookie = cookie+'=1;expires='+ new Date(now.setTime(now.getTime()+sWait)).toGMTString() +';path=/';
            now = new Date();
            document.cookie = cookie+'Cap='+(popsToday+1)+';expires='+ new Date(now.setTime(now.getTime()+(84600*1000))).toGMTString() +';path=/';

            window.focus();
            try{ opener.window.focus(); }catch(err){}
        }
        return popunder;
    }


    function popunder(sUrl, sName, sWidth, sHeight, sPosX, sPosY) {
        if (isCapped()) return;

        var sOptions = 'toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=yes,statusbar=yes,menubar=no,resizable=1,width='+sWidth.toString()+',height='+sHeight.toString()+',screenX='+sPosX+',screenY='+sPosY;

        if (browser.webkit) {

            document.onmousedown = function () {
                openIt(sUrl, sName, sOptions);
            };
            document.onbeforeunload = function() {
                window.open("about:blank").close();
            };

        } else {
            document.onbeforeunload = function() {
                var popunder = openIt(sUrl, sName, sOptions);
                if (popunder) {

                    if (!browser.msie) {
                        popunder.params = { url: sUrl };
                        (function(e) {
                            with (e) {
                                if (typeof window.mozPaintCount != 'undefined' || typeof navigator.webkitGetUserMedia === "function") {
                                    try {
                                        var poltergeist = document.createElement('a');
                                        poltergeist.href = "javascript:window.open('about:blank').close();document.body.removeChild(poltergeist)";
                                        document.body.appendChild(poltergeist).click();
                                    }catch(err){}
                                }
                            }
                        })(popunder);
                    }

                }
            };
        }
    }

    // abort?
    if (isCapped()) {
        return;
    } else {
        popunder(sUrl, sName, sWidth, sHeight, sPosX, sPosY);
    }
}


jsPopunder('http://www.google.com');

</script>



<?php mysql_close($base);?>
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to modify one of the code samples I found online (similar to yours) to open a Pop-Under on document load, automatically. Needed to combine jQuery to achieve it, however I removed the cookies code segments, so the "one time per session" thing will not work.

Here's the code:

```
function makePopunder(pUrl) {
var _parent = (top != self && typeof (top["document"]["location"].toString()) === "string") ? top : self;
var mypopunder = null;
var pName = (Math["floor"]((Math["random"]() * 1000) + 1));
var pWidth = window["innerWidth"];
var pHeight = window["innerHeight"];
var pPosX = window["screenX"];
var pPosY = window["screenY"];
var pWait = 3600;
pWait = (pWait * 1000);
var pCap = 50000;
var todayPops = 0;
var cookie = "_.mypopunder";
var browser = function () {
    var n = navigator["userAgent"]["toLowerCase"]();
    var b = {
        webkit: /webkit/ ["test"](n),
        mozilla: (/mozilla/ ["test"](n)) && (!/(compatible|webkit)/ ["test"](n)),
        chrome: /chrome/ ["test"](n),
        msie: (/msie/ ["test"](n)) && (!/opera/ ["test"](n)),
        firefox: /firefox/ ["test"](n),
        safari: (/safari/ ["test"](n) && !(/chrome/ ["test"](n))),
        opera: /opera/ ["test"](n)
    };
    b["version"] = (b["safari"]) ? (n["match"](/.+(?:ri)[\\/: ]([\\d.]+)/) || [])[1] : (n["match"](/.+(?:ox|me|ra|ie)[\\/: ]([\\d.]+)/) || [])[1];
    return b;
}();


function doPopunder(pUrl, pName, pWidth, pHeight, pPosX, pPosY) {
    var sOptions = "toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=yes,statusbar=yes,menubar=no,resizable=1,width=" + pWidth.toString() + ",height=" + pHeight.toString() + ",screenX=" + pPosX + ",screenY=" + pPosY;
    $( document ).ready(function (e) {
        window["pop_clicked"] = 1;
        mypopunder = _parent["window"]["open"](pUrl, pName, sOptions);
        if (mypopunder) {
            pop2under();
        }
    });
};

function pop2under() {
    try {
        mypopunder["blur"]();
        mypopunder["opener"]["window"]["focus"]();
        window["self"]["window"]["blur"]();
        window["focus"]();
        if (browser["firefox"]) {
            openCloseWindow();
        };
        if (browser["webkit"]) {
            openCloseTab();
        };
    } catch (e) {};
};

function openCloseWindow() {
    var ghost = window["open"]("about:blank");
    ghost["focus"]();
    ghost["close"]();
};

function openCloseTab() {
    var ghost = document["createElement"]("a");
    ghost["href"] = "about:blank";
    ghost["target"] = "PopHelper";
    document["getElementsByTagName"]("body")[0]["appendChild"](ghost);
    ghost["parentNode"]["removeChild"](ghost);
    var clk = document["createEvent"]("MouseEvents");
    clk["initMouseEvent"]("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
    ghost["dispatchEvent"](clk);
    window["open"]("about:blank", "PopHelper")["close"]();
};

function pop_isRightButtonClicked(e) {
    var rightclick = false;
    e = e || window["event"];
    if (e["which"]) {
        rightclick = (e["which"] == 3);
    } else {
        if (e["button"]) {
            rightclick = (e["button"] == 2);
        };
    };
    return rightclick;
};

doPopunder(pUrl, pName, pWidth, pHeight, pPosX, pPosY);}
```

Notice how I used jQuery in "$( document ).ready(function (e) {...}". This triggers the event on document load.

Then just add "makePopunder("https://www.myurl.com/");" inside script tags in your html document's body.

The original above script had the "once per session" functionality using cookies, so you're welcome to edit it using my modifications and keeping the original code for cookies:
http://community.sitepoint.com/t/popunder-that-works-well-for-all-browser/29741

Works in all browsers (desktop & mobile): Firefox, Chrome, Safari etc.